# Can't init Scala Gradle project: -bash: gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle: No such file or directory

Tags: scala, gradle

I just installed Gradle, manually by downloading the zip and then unzipping it, and verified it installed fine with gradle -v .

I have it located at Users/username/gradle/ . I set it on the home path for linux by running this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/
```

However, when I try to init my first Scala project, I run this command:

```
 gradle init --type scala-library
```

However, it complains that:

```
-bash: gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle: No such file or directory
```

So fine, I check my directory structure, and that file is definitely in there. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether gradle file exists and is an executable `ls -l gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle`.  Also if  Users/gradle/ means user's home directory shouldn't your path be something like  `$PATH:$HOME/gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/` ?

Comment: Sorry - made a typo in the path of where I installed Gradle, updated above: Users/username/gradle/

Doing ls -l in that drive yielded a gradle and a gradle.bat file in that folder - 

But setting the $PATH:$HOME was the error, so this: `export PATH=$PATH:gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/` needed to be `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/` Thank you!